# Google Cloud SQL CA certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How do I view/download my SQL instance CA certificate?

When I click the "View Server CA Certificate" button, this is what I see:
[image]

It doesn't appear to be there. If I click "Download server-ca.pem", it downloads an empty file.  I tried creating a new instance under a different app, same issue.

Is this a bug?  Or am I doing something incorrectly.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Con you provide some extra information? what is the Tier of your Cloud SQL instance? is it a stand alone instance or does it have any replicas? maybe the instance itself is a replica? Also, if you don't have any client SSL certificates yet, could you try clicking the `Reset SSL Configuration` button?

Comment: I'm using 2nd generation micro.  It is stand alone, not a replica.  I tried clicking "Reset SSL Configuration" and also tried building a new instance.  Same.

Are you seeing any CA certificates correctly in your console? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adam, this is a known issue that will be fixed on Thursday. Thanks for your patience :) - Gary (Google Cloud Team)

Comment: Thanks Gary.  In the meantime, is this available via the Cloud Shell?

Comment: Yep! If you take a look at these [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/configure-ssl-instance) `gcloud sql instances describe YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME --format text` should do the trick to list your server-ca.pem